# Setting up Github on a new computer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, macos, github

I am an almost perfect beginner at Github so please humor me with this elementary question.

I have a laptop PC that I've been using to interact with a repo on Github. I just bought a Mac and I would like to do my programming on both machines.

I have installed Git on the new machine and I have set up my username, e-mail, and Github token on the Terminal.

What are the basic commands I need to do this:

1. Download the repo from Github the first time? I've created a new folder on my Mac but going there and typing `git pull git@github.com/sscirrus/repo.git` produces `fatal: not a repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`.
2. Upload those changes again such that the main repo is updating cleanly with each new push. I assume that once I have the code in my new folder, it would be a matter of `git add .` and `git push` with password entry?

I am reading through tutorials on Git but just want to make sure I'm doing something sensible for my situation before my newbieness screws up a lot of prior work. Thank you!

Comment: You need to use git clone, not git push. To push back to github use git push origin master.

Comment: lakshmanan's answer is correct but I just want to point out that the example you gave won't work ever. The reason is that there is no repo there. That is just the directory that github uses to store your repos. It would look more like "git clone git@github.com/sscirrus/project.git"

Comment: Hi sosborn, thanks for your note. I do actually have a repository there, I just didn't type it's name! I appreciate you clarifying this point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go through this book, http://progit.org/book/ and http://gitcasts.com/ for video tutorial.

And I recommend you follow these steps

1. Clone the repository (*git clone repoAddress*)
2. create a new branch (*git branch branchName*)
3. checkout that branch (*git checkout branchName*)
4. make changes and commit in that branch (*git add files*)
5. checkout master (*git checkout master*)
6. perform a pull (it updates the local repository with the remote one) *git pull*
7. If there is change, checkout the branch and rebase it with local master
8. If there is conflict resolve it and add that file and make a commit again
9. checkout master again and merge the branch (*git merge branch*)
10. push the commits to the remote repository.(*git push*)

If you want a GUI tool, then there is GitX which is made for Mac OS X. http://gitx.frim.nl/

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the git repo for first time - do a clone of the repo first. this will bring your code from github to your machine for the first time.

   git clone your_git_repo_url

from second time, you can

```
git pull your_git_repo_url
```

1. Upload the changes after commits

   git push your_git_repo_url

Please read scott chacons git books. these will get you the basics of git. and learning this will help in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to use `git clone`, not `git pull`.
2. You'll want to `git commit` after `add` and before `push`. `add` just adds something to the index (Worst name ever. The "index" is essentially a pending commit.) and `commit` actually commits it to your repository. `push` then pushes committed stuff from your local repository to a remote repository.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst there's a lot to be said for using git from the command line (to help understanding) you might like to try the github clients (for mac & windows - download them from the github homepage - at the bottom in the section marked 'clients') which I'm guessing might not have been available when you posted your question.

The Windows one lets you specify a default storage directory (where it clones the repos into) - the Mac one prompts you with each clone as to where you want to stick it.

Both very easy to use to do what you want (clone, pull, push etc and also good for seeing what branches you have and changing between them)